# Navigating to multiple pages using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been working on navigating between pages using jquery mobile.I have tried with the code below.

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>site Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#Site entry1" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Enter the details of site</a>
            <a href="#Modify site" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Modify site details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="Site entry1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <h1>Welcome To enter the details of site</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-primary">
                <form>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="sitename">Site name:</label>
                        <input type="text" sitename="name" id="sitename" value="" />
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="siteno">Site name:</label>
                        <input type="text" siteno="siteno" id="siteno" value="" />
                    </li>
                    <a href="#Site entry2" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Next</a>
                </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="Site entry2">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a href="#Site entry1" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">previous</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="content-primary">
                    <form>
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="moduleno">name:</label>
                            <input type="text" modulename="moduleno" id="moduleno" value="" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                                <div class="ui-block-b">
                                    <button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer">
                    <a href="#Site entry3" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="page" id="Site entry3">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <a href="#Site entry2" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">previous</a>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <div class="content-primary">
                        <form>
                        <ul data-role="listview">
                            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <label for="modulename">name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                                        <button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="footer">
                        <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="page" id="Modify site">
                    <div data-role="header">
                        <a href="home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                        <h1>List of sites </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="content"></div>
                    <div data-role="footer"></div>
                </div>
</body>
```

But i cant be able to navigate from Site entry1 page to the Site entry2 and from modify button in home screen to the respected page.I need to persist the data from site entry page1 to site entry page3 untill i press submit button.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you have not closed the divisions properly

Comment: ID should not be separated by space, it should be one word and unique. use hyphen, underscore or just stick them together.

Comment: it does'nt matter @Omar in case of page id's ..It will still work the problem is with not closing the divisions properly and that i corrected in code given below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>site Details</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

<a href="#Site entry1" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Enter the details of site</a>

<a href="#Modify site" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Modify site details</a>

</div>

 </div>

<div data-role="page" id="Site entry1">

<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    <h1>Welcome To enter the details of site</h1>
    </div>


<div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">
    <form>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="sitename">Site name:</label>
            <input type="text" sitename="name" id="sitename" value=""  />
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="siteno">Site name:</label>
            <input type="text" siteno="siteno" id="siteno" value=""  />
        </li>

        <a href="#Site entry2" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Next</a>

    </ul>

    </form>
    </div>


</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="Site entry2">

    <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#Site entry1"  data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">previous</a>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
        <form>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="moduleno">name:</label>
                <input type="text" modulename="moduleno" id="moduleno" value=""  />
            </li>
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                    </fieldset>
            </li>

        </ul>

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    <a href="#Site entry3" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
    </div>


</div>

<div data-role="page" id="Site entry3">

    <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#Site entry2" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">previous</a>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
        <form>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="modulename">name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
            </li>

            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                    </fieldset>
            </li>

        </ul>

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    <a href="#home"  data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="Modify site">

    <div data-role="header">
    <a href="home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    <h1>List of sites </h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

correct code